# npm --version is different if use sudo npm --version

Tags: 14.04, sudo, nodejs, npm

I have just upgraded nodejs in my machine. I uninstalled the node version (the one in ubuntu repositories) that I had. Then I installed nvm and installed nodejs 4.2.2.

Everything goes without errors, but when I ran `npm --version` it showed 2.14.7, then I decided to run: `sudo npm install -g npm` in order to upgrade npm version, but when I checked it, it was still showing 2.14.7. So, I checked once again but using `sudo npm --version` this time, and there was the latest 3.3.10 version.

Why this happens and how can I fix it?

Here is a screenshot:
[image: Different npm version is showed with or without sudo]

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Edit:

adding wich command outputs

```
sistemas@ITAACO01:~$ which npm
/home/sistemas/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.2/bin/npm
sistemas@ITAACO01:~$ sudo which npm
/usr/local/bin/npm
```

Comment: [edit] your question and add the outputs of `which npm` and `sudo which npm` please. Then leave me a comment (@ByteCommander) to notify me.

Comment: @ByteCommander Hi, I just added the wich command outputs.

Comment: The `.nvm` version has been installed with [nvm — Node Version Manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).  You can run `nvm ls` to see all the versions installed with it. `nvm --help` will list other useful commands...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears (from the `which` outputs) that your user (`sistemas`) is set to use a different, outdated version of `npm` located at `/home/sistemas/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.2/bin/npm` - ignoring the updated, system-wide version at `/usr/local/bin/npm`.

Check if `/usr/local/bin` is in your `$PATH`. (Do `echo $PATH` and see if its output contains `/usr/local/bin`.

If not, add it (put `PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"` in your `~/.bash_profile`)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibilities :

1. The new version path is not present:

   Add the path. For example : Add `/usr/local/bin/npm` to the path
2. The older version is earlier in the `$PATH`:

   Remove the older version path. For example: Remove `/home/sistemas/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.2/bin/npm` from `$PATH`